# Alternative of numpy.linalg.pinv in tensorflow

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, tensorflow

I am looking for a alternative of numpy.linalg.pinv in tensorflow.
So far I have found that tensorflow have only `tf.matrix_inverse(input, adjoint=None, name=None)` which throws an error if matrix in not invertible.

Comment: you could alternatively use regularization in case a matrix is not invertible.

Comment: @NikolasRieble, please provide an example

Comment: `pinv()` is based on SVD, and Tensorflow has a SVD function... I'm not going to provide an example :)

Answer (score 7):

TensorFlow provides an SVD op, so you can compute the pseudo-inverse from that quite easily:

```
def pinv(A, b, reltol=1e-6):
  # Compute the SVD of the input matrix A
  s, u, v = tf.svd(A)

  # Invert s, clear entries lower than reltol*s[0].
  atol = tf.reduce_max(s) * reltol
  s = tf.boolean_mask(s, s > atol)
  s_inv = tf.diag(tf.concat([1. / s, tf.zeros([tf.size(b) - tf.size(s)])], 0))

  # Compute v * s_inv * u_t * b from the left to avoid forming large intermediate matrices.
  return tf.matmul(v, tf.matmul(s_inv, tf.matmul(u, tf.reshape(b, [-1, 1]), transpose_a=True)))
```

Comment: +1, this should be the accepted answer. However, perhaps make `b` optional? Users may need the pseudo-inverse for some other purpose than to compute A+ * b?

Comment: I think, one could replace the last two lines by:
    s_inv = tf.diag(1. / s). 
    return tf.matmul(v, tf.matmul(s_inv, u, transpose_b=True))

Answer (score 4):

An implementation that follows numpy's [`pinv`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.pinv.html) implementation:

```
def pinv(a, rcond=1e-15):
    s, u, v = tf.svd(a)
    # Ignore singular values close to zero to prevent numerical overflow
    limit = rcond * tf.reduce_max(s)
    non_zero = tf.greater(s, limit)

    reciprocal = tf.where(non_zero, tf.reciprocal(s), tf.zeros(s.shape))
    lhs = tf.matmul(v, tf.matrix_diag(reciprocal))
    return tf.matmul(lhs, u, transpose_b=True)
```

This supports both single and batch computations of pseudo-inverses:

```
# Pseudo-inverse of one (4, 3) matrix, has shape (3, 4)
pinv(tf.random_normal((4, 3)))

# Pseudo-inverses of two (4, 3) matrices, has shape (2, 3, 4)
pinv(tf.random_normal((2, 4, 3)))
```

Thank you @Andy Tsai for the hint!

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of numpy.linalg.pinv alternatives in tensorflow, yet regularization is an alternative in case a matrix is not invertible. An example:

```
try: 
    result = tf.matrix_inverse(input, adjoint=None, name=None)
except: 
    input += np.identity((input.shape))* c 
    result = tf.matrix_inverse(input, adjoint=None, name=None)
```

Where c is a constant and should be very small such as c = 0.000001

Yet matrix inversion is rather expensive computationally and should only be done if neccesary. For more information see: [do not invert that matrix](https://www.johndcook.com/blog/2010/01/19/dont-invert-that-matrix/)

Comment: Expanding on you final remark, if the OP has to solve _`A x = b`_ they can find `x` in terms of `x ← pinv(A)@b` (the route the OP implies) or (following your suggestion) they can do as follows: `b^ ← A.T@b`, `A^  ← A.T@A` and solve, using e.g. LU factorization, the linear system _`A^ x = b^`_

Comment: The `except` block will never be called. The call to `tf.matrix_inverse(input, adjoint=None, name=None)` simply adds the corresponding ops to the graph. It doesn't check if the input is invertible, since the input itself is just a tensor without any values yet. You will still run into the `InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): Input is not invertible.`

Answer (score 1):

You can combine the [tf.py_func](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/py_func) of `tensorflow` with `numpy`'s [pseudo-inverse](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.12.0/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.pinv.html) as follows:

```
return tf.py_func(np.linalg.pinv, [input], tf.float32)
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to support batching for faster computing is to replace `tf.diag` with `tf.matrix_diag`. Something like this:

```
def pinv(a, rcond=1e-15):
    s, u, v = tf.svd(a)
    # Ignore singular values close to zero to prevent numerical overflow
    limit = rcond * tf.reduce_max(s)
    non_zero = tf.greater(s, limit)

    reciprocal = tf.where(non_zero, tf.reciprocal(s), tf.zeros(s.shape))
    lhs = tf.matmul(v, tf.matrix_diag(reciprocal))
    return tf.matmul(lhs, u, transpose_b=True)
```